# PHP array to ordered & nested HTML list

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, list, nested-sortable

I'm using the jQuery [nestedSortable plugin](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) in a project.  When a list item is moved, I serialize the array and save it to my db.  I'm having trouble recreating the HTML list from the PHP array.  Probably because it's late. :)

I have the following PHP array:

```
Array
(
    [list_4] => root
    [list_3] => 4
    [list_1303966373] => 3
    [list_1] => 1303966373
    [list_5] => 1
    [list_2] => 1
    [list_6] => root
)
```

It should make a list something like...

```
<ol>
<li id='list_4'>value 4
  <ol>
    <li id='list_3'>value 3
      <ol>
        <li id='list_1303966373'>value 1303966373
          <ol>
            <li id='list_1'>value 1
              <ol>
                <li id='list_5'>value 5</li>
                <li id='list_2'>value 2</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</li>
<li id='list_6'>value 6</li>          
</ol>
```

(Ignore the values, they're just there for show.)

The HTML list could have any depth of nested lists.

My brain is dead and I cannot get it to work.  Anyone have a suggestion?  I'll owe you cookies for eternity.  Also, a castle.

Thanks. :)

Comment: This isn't the concern of the question, but you may want to investigate other ways to save such a list to your database.

Comment: Please don't start id's with numbers, it makes babies cry http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html (see it's even in the docs)

Comment: hey guys, that's really just for show.  the actual list has ids prepended with "list_"  I'll edit the ex to make the babies feel better. :)

Comment: @zneak   That's true.  After this problem is solved, I intend to save the parent id with each row of the "values" table I use to keep info on each individual <li> item.  I'll still run into the issue though, so I figured I'd cross this bridge first.

Comment: @Dylan - Why don't you try [jquery treeview](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) for this...?

Comment: @Nirmal I needed to use drag and drop functionality in the list.  Treeview is awesome but adding the nestedSortable functionality to it seems tough. :)

Comment: @Dylan : Well, if you want drag and drop feature, then i don't think so you should use treeview.... But for sortable, I think you can override the jquery-treeview-async.js with your requirements...

Comment: @Nirmal  Yeah, thanks!  Unfortunately the drag & drop is necessary.

Comment: @Dylan : May be (1) http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jquerydragdrop/ (2) http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ can help you...

Comment: @Nirmal  This plugin: http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/  actually does all the heavy lifting for me. :)  Now I'm just trying to fetch the list from the db and show it appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have it (tested OK with your sample):

```
<?php
  $tree = array(
    "list_4" => "root",
    "list_3" => "list_4",
    "list_1303966373" => "list_3",
    "list_1" => "list_1303966373",
    "list_5" => "list_1",
    "list_2" => "list_1",
    "list_6" => "root",
 );
 function getChildrenLists($tree){
    $tree2 = array();
    foreach($tree as $child => $parent){
       if(!array_key_exists($parent, $tree2)) $tree2[$parent] = array();
       $tree2[$parent][] = $child;
    }
    return $tree2;
 }

 function renderTree($tree2, $parent = "root"){
    if($parent != "root") echo "<li id='$parent'> value $parent\n";
    $children = $tree2[$parent];
    if(count($children) > 0){ //If node has children
       echo "<ol>\n";
       foreach($children as $child)
          renderTree($tree2, $child);
       echo "</ol>\n";
    }
    if($parent != "root") echo "</li>\n";
 }
 $tree2 = getChildrenLists($tree); 
 renderTree($tree2);

?>
```

I want my cookie! Hehe. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you might just be the bomb.com.  Thank you thank you thank you!